# Can't insert 535.5357055664062 to JSON field of Google Cloud Spanner

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

Some floats are not available to insert into JSON fields.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid value for bind parameter json: Expected JSON.",
    "status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

examples)

Invalid float

- `535.5357055664062`

Valid float

- `535.535705566406`
- `103.3588679387016812112421411`

They are valid for `FLAOT64` type, so can be inserted into FLOAT64 fields.

Comment: you should post the exact request you are sending (minus sensitive data like api key or pi)

Comment: @GarrGodfrey I want to do that, but I checked it with Google Cloud Spanner console. You can reproduce it easily.

Answer (score 2):

+1 to Knut's answer. See also relevant documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/working-with-json#specifications

If you do not care about round-trip through string representation the documentation points to: `PARSE_JSON('<float_string>', wide_number_mode='round')`, see also: https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/json_functions#parse_json .

Would this help in your case?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is caused by Cloud Spanner trying to ensure that the string representation of the stored JSON value will be equal to the input. The decimal value `535.5357055664062` would be stored as float value `535.53570556640625`. So you have:

- `535.5357055664062` vs
- `535.53570556640625`

When the latter is rounded, it will return `535.5357055664063`, which is different from the initial value.

Compare that to the decimal value `535.535705566406` which will translate to float value `535.53570556640625`, so you have:

- `535.535705566406`
- `535.53570556640625`

When the latter is rounded, it will still return `535.535705566406`.

The error message you are getting is somewhat confusing, so it would be interesting to know exactly how you are doing it. I tried the following using DBeaver and only SQL statements and no parameters, and got a somewhat more fitting error message:

```sql
create table jsontest (id int64, value json) primary key (id);

insert into jsontest (id, value) values (1, json '{"value": 535.5357055664062}');
```

The above returns the following error message:

```
SQL Error [3]: INVALID_ARGUMENT: com.google.api.gax.rpc.InvalidArgumentException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid JSON literal: Input number: 535.5357055664062 cannot round-trip through string representation [at 1:45]
insert into jsontest (id, value) values (1, json '{"value": 535.5357055664062}')
```

You can easily try which values will be accepted and which will not by just executing a simple `SELECT JSON '<any-random-float>'` statement. For example:

```sql
-- This succeeds:
select json '535.5357055664063';

-- This fails:
select json '535.53570556640631';
```

(I understand that this does not solve your problem, but it seems that this is the intended behavior of the JSON data type in Cloud Spanner. Any questions regarding the feature itself should probably be done through the support channels of the product.)